# Rails 3 Validation :presence => false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Here's what I expected to be a perfectly straightforward question, but I can't find a definitive answer in the Guides or elsewhere.

I have two attributes on an ActiveRecord.  I want exactly one to be present and the other to be nil or a blank string.

How do I do the equivalent of :presence => false?  I want to make sure the value is nil.

```
validates :first_attribute, :presence => true, :if => "second_attribute.blank?"
validates :second_attribute, :presence => true, :if => "first_attribute.blank?"
# The two lines below fail because 'false' is an invalid option
validates :first_attribute, :presence => false, :if => "!second_attribute.blank?"
validates :second_attribute, :presence => false, :if => "!first_attribute.blank?"
```

Or perhaps there's a more elegant way to do this...

I'm running Rails 3.0.9

Comment: I'm not sure you need the :presence => false at all in the last two lines of code.

Comment: @creativetechnologist It needs a test of some sort. If I get rid of the :presence validation, it gives me: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.
0.9/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:79:in `validates': You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)

Comment: Worth noting for Rails 4 that this is called `validates_absence_of`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class NoPresenceValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)                                   
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'must be blank') unless record.send(attribute).blank?
  end                                                                           
end    

validates :first_attribute, :presence => true, :if => "second_attribute.blank?"
validates :second_attribute, :presence => true, :if => "first_attribute.blank?"

validates :first_attribute, :no_presence => true, :if => "!second_attribute.blank?"
validates :second_attribute, :no_presence => true, :if => "!first_attribute.blank?"
```

Answer (score 44):

For allowing an object to be valid if and only if a specific attribute is nil, you can use "inclusion" rather than creating your own method.

```
validates :name, inclusion: { in: [nil] }
```

This is for Rails 3.  The Rails 4 solution is much more elegant:

```
validates :name, absence: true
```

Answer (score 4):

use custom validation.

```rb
validate :validate_method

# validate if which one required other should be blank
def validate_method
  errors.add(:field, :blank) if condition
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like :length => { :is => 0 } works for what I need.

```
validates :first_attribute, :length => {:is => 0 }, :unless => "second_attribute.blank?"
```

Comment: This has the error message "is the wrong length (should be 0 characters)". Can add a custom message "must be blank".

    `validates :first_attribute, :length => {:is => 0, :message => "must be blank" }, :unless => "second_attribute.blank?"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
validates :first_attribute, :presence => {:if => second_attribute.blank?}
validates :second_attribute, :presence => {:if => (first_attribute.blank? && second_attribute.blank? )}
```

Hope that help .