# Enforce mutually exclusive fields' presence in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This code isn't working for me, but the debugger does trigger, and the values are what I expect for my test case:

```
validates :a, :presence => false, :if => Proc.new { |f| debugger; f.b.present? }
validates :b, :presence => false, :if => Proc.new { |f| debugger; f.a.present? }
```

Goal: `a` and `b` should never be defined at the same time.

If I understand the syntax, `a`'s presence should be `false` if `b` is present.  And similar for `b`.

Am I misunderstanding this?  I do believe the data is recorded via `save!` .. but then I've already confirmed the validations are being called.  I looked at the object immediately after `obj.save!` and the `obj.errors` has an empty `messages` hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the 'if' logic -- `presence: false` is NOT the opposite of `presence: true`

Reference: [Rails 3 Validation :presence => false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070786/rails-3-validation-presence-false)

I ended up using:

```
validates :a, length: {is: 0}, if: Proc.new { |f| f.b.present? }
validates :b, length: {is: 0}, if: Proc.new { |f| f.a.present? }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something that might make this simpler would be to call a custom validation that just checks if either is present using self without calling length or creating a proc.

```
validate :are_mutually_exclusive

private

def are_mutually_exclusive
  if self.a.present? && self.b.present?
    errors.add(:your_error_key, 'Values for A and B are mutually exclusive')
  end
end
```

These are also easier to manage if you have grouped values. E.g. A & B are allowed together, but neither A or B is allowed with C

```
if (self.a.present? || self.b.present?) && self.c.present?
```